# Defining natural numbers as the posterity of 0

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, foundations

In the *Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy* (1, p.26), Bertrand Russell defines natural numbers in the following way:

> The “natural numbers” are the posterity of $0$ with respect to the 
>   relation “immediate predecessor” (which is the converse of “successor”).

Where:

> [...] the “posterity” of a given natural number with respect
>   to the relation “immediate predecessor” (which is the converse
>   of “successor”) as all those terms that belong to every hereditary class
>   to which the given number belongs.

Now, a *class* may be defined by *extension* (enumeration) or by *intention* (defining property). I don't see how we can use extension in the above definition, so I assume Russell means *every hereditary class defined by any property to which the given number ($0$) belongs*.

How do we know $0$ possesses any such property?

PS. I found similar question on SE ([What does Russell mean when he defines the “Posterity… with respect to the immediate predecessor”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252608/what-does-russell-mean-when-he-defines-the-posterity-with-respect-to-the-immed)). However, there is no mention about defining properties.

(1) https://people.umass.edu/klement/imp/imp.pdf

Comment: To say that the *posterity* is the class of "all those terms that belong to every hereditary class to which the given number belongs" means *the intersection of all the hereditary classes to which the given number belongs*.

Comment: We define the *posterity* of every number $n$, but obviously only the *posterity* of $0$ will include **all** the natural numbers.

Comment: I understand that. What confuses me is that we still need (I think) _properties_ to define classes to which 0 belongs. How do we know 0 belongs to any class? Is it just assumed?

Comment: This definition was due to Frege; for a modern exposition, see [Frege's Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/).

Comment: In Frege's logic, every property defines a class; see the [Comprehension Principle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#1.3).

Comment: In modern set theory (see: [Enderton](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA69), page 69) we define an *inductive set* as a set def include $0$ and is closed under the *successor* operation, and then we define the set $\omega$ of natural as the intersection of all inductive sets (there is an axiom asserting that there is at least one inductive set: the *axiom of infinity*; the same for Russell's logic).

Comment: Okay, so it's a axiom. Thank you.